# How to divide data from each year from sum of each year in base

Tags: r

```
sales <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Year Name Sales
1980 Atari 4.00
1980 Activision 1.07
1981 Activision 4.21
1981 ParkerBros. 2.06
1981 Imagic 1.99
1981 Atari 1.84
1981 Coleco 1.36
1981 Mystique 0.76
1981 Fox 0.74
1981 Men 0.72")
```

[image: data]

I was able to get the sum using aggregate.
I want to divide sales data from that year's total sales and get the %. But I don't know how to divide each row from respective year's total sales.

```
DF <- aggregate(Sales ~ Year + NAame, data = sales, FUN=sum)
DFC48 <- aggregate(DF, NA_Sales~Year, FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

We could use `ave()`. Here we can apply function `x/sum(x)` to each group `Year`, where `x` is defined by `sales$Sales`:

```
sales$su <- ave(sales$Sales, sales$Year, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))
```

```
  Year        Name Sales         su
1  1980       Atari  4.00 0.78895464
2  1980  Activision  1.07 0.21104536
3  1981  Activision  4.21 0.30774854
4  1981 ParkerBros.  2.06 0.15058480
5  1981      Imagic  1.99 0.14546784
6  1981       Atari  1.84 0.13450292
7  1981      Coleco  1.36 0.09941520
8  1981    Mystique  0.76 0.05555556
9  1981         Fox  0.74 0.05409357
10 1981         Men  0.72 0.05263158
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the below code

```r
data %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(su=Sales/sum(Sales))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 4
# Groups:   Year [2]
    Year Name         Sales     su
   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1980 Atari         4    0.789 
 2  1980 Activision    1.07 0.211 
 3  1981 Activision    4.21 0.308 
 4  1981 Parker Bros.  2.06 0.151 
 5  1981 Imagic        1.99 0.145 
 6  1981 Atari         1.84 0.135 
 7  1981 Coleco        1.36 0.0994
 8  1981 Mystique      0.76 0.0556
 9  1981 Fox           0.74 0.0541
10  1981 Men           0.72 0.0526
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `prop.table` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
sales %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(su = prop.table(Sales))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Groups:   Year [2]
#>     Year Name        Sales     su
#>    <int> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  1980 Atari        4    0.789 
#>  2  1980 Activision   1.07 0.211 
#>  3  1981 Activision   4.21 0.308 
#>  4  1981 ParkerBros.  2.06 0.151 
#>  5  1981 Imagic       1.99 0.145 
#>  6  1981 Atari        1.84 0.135 
#>  7  1981 Coleco       1.36 0.0994
#>  8  1981 Mystique     0.76 0.0556
#>  9  1981 Fox          0.74 0.0541
#> 10  1981 Men          0.72 0.0526
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>